# How can I generate custom XML for a SOAP client?

Tags: 8, theming

Im building a SOAP client that consumes from a SOAP web services in a Drupal 8 module.

I need to generate this final XML:

```
$inpunt_data = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:qual="http://websoap.com/">

                           <soapenv:Header/>

                           <soapenv:Body>

                              <qual:myMethod>

                                 <!--Optional:-->

                                 <qual:xmlMethod><![CDATA[

                                <Tag>
                                </Tag>
                               </qual:Method>';
```

How do I generate soapenv headers?

I'm using simplexml:

```
$getXML = new SimpleXMLElement($input_data);  
             $urlTarifa = 'http://soapurl.com?wsdl';
             $client = new SoapClient($urlTarifa);
```

Comment: Why not use the PHP SOAP client? https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I've done it:

some-feed.html.twig

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <atom:link href="{{ some_variable_set_in_preprocess }}" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
      /* -- rest of feed omitted */
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Then hook_theme() to register the template:

```
function hook_theme() {
  return [
    'some_feed' => [
      'render element' => 'elements',
      'template' => 'some-feed',
    ],
  ];
}
```

You can then generate a response with that theme:

```
$build = [
  '#theme' => 'some_feed',
];

$response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response();
$xml = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($build);
$response->setContent($xml);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```

You now have a Response object to work with. Depending on where you are working, you can return that, or set it as a response.

Comment: Im doing this on a custom module, inside a controller, then, i send the variables to the twig...i will try!